# Different context name for webview in Hybrid Android App test through Appium

Tags: android, appium

While testing Hybrid android app in Appium, a change of context from NATIVE to WEBVIEW is expected. But, the name of the WEBVIEW context does not remain same at all instance of testing. However, it is one of the follwing:

> WEBVIEW_undefined
>
> WEBVIEW_{package_name_of_application_under_test}

Say, I'm testing a Hybrid app with package name

> com.webviewbrowser

In this case, the context name of the WEBVIEW switches randomly between the following two at every instance

> WEBVIEW_undefined
>
> WEBVIEW_com.webviewbrowser

When I use the following in my code,

```
driver.context("WEBVIEW_com.webviewbrowser")
```

Miserably, I actually receive the context name  **WEBVIEW_undefined** sometimes and **NosuchContextException** is thrown.

Why does this happen even when no other app is running at the time of testing?

How do I get rid of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

try adding : `capabilities.SetCapability("autoWebview", "true");`

or

When you are switching between 2 web views try to switch like this:

```
ReadOnlyCollection<string> windowHandles = InitialiseAppium.driver.WindowHandles;
InitialiseAppium.driver.SwitchTo().Window(windowHandles[1]);
```